# Callout to Dynamics regularly results in timeout, is it a problem in Salesforce or in Dynamics?

Tags: webservices, soap

I am using WebServiceCallout.invoke inside a batch to call a SOAP webservice in Dynamics AX. The batch size is 1.
What I am seeing: after 9 or 10 fast (1 second) and successful callouts, the next one fails with an error message:

> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after
>   00:01:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or
>   increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to
>   this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

After that, 9 or 10 fast and successful callouts, and then another timeout. Etcetera, etcetera.

The problem is not with the request per se: if I fire it individually, it returns data in 1 second.

The timeout for WebServiceCallout.invoke is set to 2 minutes. The Dynamics people are reluctant to increase the timeout on their side and I think I agree with them that it will not solve the problem. The callout will probably still timeout and not return data. They ask: are you closing your connections?

I don't know, I just use WebServiceCallout.invoke. It's the only method in the WebServiceCallout class. Also, I can't find a way to pass options to invoke that have something to do with closing. Anybody seen this before? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the other side.

Answer (score 0):

You can try do create a [HTTP Callout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_http.htm). One of the methods of the methods of the [HTTPRequest class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm#apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest) is the `setTimout(Integer timeout)` that allows you to set the time out. That could also let you handle the time out exception.

```java
public class HttpCalloutSample {

  // Pass in the endpoint to be used using the string url
  public String getCalloutResponseContents(String url) {

    // Instantiate a new http object
    Http h = new Http();

     // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setTimeOut(3000); //3s (The timeout can be any value between 1 and 120,000 milliseconds)

    // Send the request, and return a response
    try{
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        return res.getBody();
    }catch(Exception e){
        //handle timeout exception
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: WebServiceCallout.invoke has an option to set a timeout. It's set to 2 minutes. I added it to my question, I had forgotten. The timeout error is generated by the server.